# Using conditional formatting with multiple conditions to color format cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, forex

I am trying to find the most efficient way to give my times a color code (4 different colors) based on what trading session the alert was triggered (London, London & USA, USA, and After Hours).  I have tried a number of ways but none have provided a proper result.

For example, if an alert was triggered at 07:05:33, then that triggered occurred in the LONDON & USA session and should be colored green.  If an alert was at 02:22:33, then that was in the London session and that field should be colored blue.  These are just a few examples. If no time value is provided, then the appropriate field needs to remain unfilled.  I wanted to include a photo but haven't built up enough reputation points as of yet.  So... I am going to try and give a verbal snapshot of what I have and describe it to the best of my ability.

My alert signals are located e11:e61... the E column is the one that I would like to color.

Sessions are as follows...

```
London Only    2:00:00 - 6:59:59  (Dark Blue)
London & USA   7:00:00 - 9:59:59  (Green)
USA Only       10:00:00 - 4:00:00 (Dark Orange)
After Hours    4:00:01 - 23:59:59 (Light Blue)
After Hours    0:00:01 - 01:59:59
```

Not sure how I can program this entire column in Excel to do this.  I have seen multiple colors on spreadsheets, but do not know if it is manual or automatic.  I would assume automatic due to the amount of data and time that it would take to color each of the cells.

Didn't know if I could program this directly by the input cells.  If not, I also set up a small session reference table.

```
J5:K5 represent 2:00:00 - 06:59:59
J6:K6 represent 07:00:00 - 09:59:59
J7:K7 represent 10:00:00 - 4:00:00
J8:K8 represent 04:00:01 - 23:59:59
J9:K9 represent 00:00:01 - 01:59:59
```

Not sure it is needed, if not... I will remove.  Whatever suggestions / recommendations would be a huge help.

Comment: I hope my description above is clear, and thanks Tim for representing my data in a very organized fashion.   An example, my first entry for E11 is 07:05:00.  I am needing a calculation that analyzes which timeframe (or trading session) this time falls within. Once that session has been determined, the calculation will then need to assign a color code for that trading session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by following the below steps:

1. Home>Style>Conditional Formatting
2. Create New Rule - "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
3. I had to create 5 different rules due to my session time setup.
4. Each rule followed the basic setup: =AND($e11>=TIME(7,0,0),$e11<=TIME(9,59,59))
5. I only had to change the time data for each of the five.

It is working perfectly now!  Hope that this is hellpful to others.

Comment: pnuts... it is actually 5 time sessions into 4 colors

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically apply conditional formatting to Excel spreadsheets with built-in functions. These will update the cell's color based off the value of the cell, which can be controlled in real-time updates. This works in both [newer](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67) (2010+) and [older](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cformatting.htm) versions of Microsoft Office, although newer versions of Office support these features which do not appear in older versions:

- Data Bars
- Color Scales
- Icon Sets

Comment: fond42518... I have been trying to program a formula using Home>Style>Conditional Formatting.  However, I must not be doing something correctly because no cells are being colored.  Not sure what the proper input formula should be at this point.

Comment: I noticed with the Data Bars, Color Scales, and Icon Sets... that those three options do not work with what I am trying to do. I believe that I have to do some sort of formula/statement that is true and then assign a color.  However, just haven't figured out how YET!

Comment: Could you possibly upload your file, and post a link in the comments? I'd love to help you!

Comment: I was able to solve the question through a lot of trial and error.  I am new to the area, and don't have enough reputation points to upload a file or post images.  See above for the solution that I came up with.

Comment: Great! Glad you were able to get this straightened out. BTW, when I said "post a link", I meant to upload the file to an external sharing site, and posting a sharing link. Happy New Year!

Comment: fond42518... what is a good external sharing site that you would recommend for the future?  That could be extremely helpful.   On a totally different thought, do you have any explanation why my reputation is going down?  I try and follow the guidelines.   Happy New Year to you as well.